# Retrofit Error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, retrofit, java.lang.class

URL Link : http://www.factsplanet.info/cities.php
Method Retrofit
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

**Main Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Retrofit retrofit;
    Factory service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://factsplanet.info/")
                .build();

       service = retrofit.create(Factory.class);

        Call<ThisIsPojo> call = service.getnames();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ThisIsPojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ThisIsPojo> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getData().get(1).getCountry(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Interface Class:**

```
public interface Factory {

@GET ("http://www.factsplanet.info/cities.php")
    Call<ThisIsPojo>  getnames();
}
```

POJO CLASS:

public class ThisIsPojo {

```
    private List<Datum> data = null;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

**Error Says:**
*java.lang.RuntimeException*: Unable to start activity

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:* Unable to create converter for class app.com.alphaapps.android.suntest.pojo.ThisIsPojo                                                                                  for method Factory.getnames

Comment: You should register a converter factory.

Comment: please show your Pojo class code.

Comment: you are missing a convertor `new Retrofit.Builder()..baseUrl("https://factsplanet.info/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

Comment: Create Gson Pojo

Comment: Edit it in your question, not in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify it like this:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://factsplanet.info/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try this way  if it can help

**Service Interface**

```
public interface ServiceInterface {
    @GET(HttpConstants.CITIESJSON)
    Call<GeonameResponse>getCities(@Query("north")double north, @Query("south")double south, @Query("east")double east, @Query("west")double west, @Query("lang")String lang, @Query("username")String username);

    @GET(HttpConstants.USERDATAJSON)
    Call<ListData>taskData(@Query("method")String method,@Query("stdID")int stdID);

    @POST(HttpConstants.USERDATAJSON)
    Call<ListData> saveUser(@Body DataPojo pojo);
}
```

**ServiceClass**

```
public class ServiceClass {
    static ServiceInterface serviceInterface;
//    public static final String baseUrl= HttpConstants.BASE_URL_GEONAME;
    public static final String baseUrl= HttpConstants.baseUrl;

    public static ServiceInterface connection(){
        if(serviceInterface==null){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Response response=chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    return response;
                }
            });
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .build();
            serviceInterface=retrofit.create(ServiceInterface.class);
        }
        return serviceInterface;
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public void addUser(DataPojo pojo){
        ServiceInterface serviceInterface=ServiceClass.connection();
        Call<ListData> call=serviceInterface.saveUser(pojo);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ListData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                Log.v("@@@Response",""+response.toString());
                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    Toast.makeText(AddNewUser.this,"User Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    supportFinishAfterTransition();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.v("@@@Failure"," Message"+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

For the whole example please visit below link 
https://github.com/pratikvyas1991/NetworkingExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/ims/tasol/networkingexample